# lsinitrd shows no module in 18.04.1

Tags: boot, kernel, initrd

In my experience in CentOS7, just type

```
lsinitrd
```

I can get modules in initrd, but in Ubuntu 18, I need to type

```
lsinitd /boot/initrd.img-4.xxxx-generic
```

However, it still show nothing about module.

Comment: What do you want to see?

Comment: I found CentOS7 didn't include usb driver which caused dd image can't boot in USB. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457124/dd-copy-a-hdd-to-usb-but-fail-to-boot I want to check ubuntu has the same problem or not.

Comment: `usb-storage` is included.

Comment: how to verify since lsinitrd didn't list it.